# How to access dynamically generated QWidgets?

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a function which generates a QGroupBox with a couple of other elements inside (Buttons, LineEdits, Checkboxes).

`def generate_whole_form(self, testbed) -> QGroupBox:`

This function is called in a loop, the returned QGroupBox is appended to an array (`self.gridArray.append(current_groupbox)`) and then put inside a QGridLayout (`self.gridlayout.append(current_groupbox)`).

I would now like to access the elemets inside the GroupBoxes and I figured there are two ways of doing it:

1. My `generate_whole_form()` returns not only the QGroupBox, but also all the other elements I need to deal with later on. Then I could save these handles within the loop.
2. I could do something like this: `self.gridArray[number].findChild(QWidget.QButton, "my_set_objectName")` to have access to the single UI elements.

Version 2 seems to be the easier option, as I would not need to manage all the returned UI objects. In fact, I already started implementing it this way, but for some reason, my program breaks, whenever I call `findChild()`. However, it works fine when I use `findChildren()`.

I would like to know if one of the above mentioned ways is better than the other or if there is even a third way. If version two is preferred, what is going wrong when I use `findChild()`? How can I use this function correctly?

Comment: You should clarify what do you *actually* need to access and how/when/why. Also, if your syntax for `findChild` is *exactly* what you've written, your program will crash because of syntax errors: it should be `findChild(QtWidgets.QPushButton, "my_set_objectName")`, since `QWidget` is not a module, and there's no such thing as `QButton`. Also, you should consider that python lists are ***not*** arrays: an array is a collection of items of *the same type*.

Comment: If you ensure all the child widgets have unique names (i.e. relative to their parent group-box), then you could do `self.gridArray[number].findChild(object, name)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler solution is to create a QGroupBox where the widgets are owned:

```
class CustomGroupBox(QGroupBox):
    def __init__(self, params, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._widgets = dict()
 
        for param in params:
            # TODO: create widget using param
            widget = QWidget() 
            # TODO: add layout
            self.widgets[custom_key] = widget

    @property
    def widgets(self):
        return self._widgets
```

Then:

```
group_box = CustomGroupBox(...)
print(group_box.widgets)
```